# Navigation page shows blank screen in .net maui

Tags: c#, maui

I have come to realize that there is a bug in .net Maui. Navigation page shows blank screen. However a work around was provided on GitHub community and I was wondering if anybody has been able to implement it.

This is the link https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1124#issuecomment-852261127

Any help will be appreciated

This is what I did.
In app.xaml.cs my mainpage is set like this MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login page);

But this navigates to empty pages not only in one app but almost all the apps I develop.

Somebody on GitHub provided a solution but I don't understand how to use it. Is there anybody who can help me out with this?
Here is the link.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1124#issuecomment-852261127

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: this bug is over two years old - I don't see this behavior in a current MAUI install.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I am using .net6.0 for this project

Comment: 1) *"But this navigates to empty pages"*: Add to question the line of code you use to navigate to another page. 2) TRY: In MauiProgram.cs, before `.Build();`, add `.UseMauiControlHandlers()`. Might need `using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting;` at top of file.

Comment: ToolmakerSteve, thanks alot but that is what I did at the very first time, however Maui keeps saying that doesn't recognize it in the current context though I added the namespace I was told to add

Comment: People are working on fixing bugs in 8.0. We are getting something (at least for now) in the 7.0. And backporting to 6.0 is getting next to nothing. And all you have to do is change one number to upgrade it. Any point for keeping 6?

Comment: It actually happened that I had  created this project before .net 7 and I feel that if I upgrade to .net7 might affect my project in some way.

Comment: I testd the `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login page);` in my .net 6.0 project. But  I didn't meet your problem. I used Visual Studio version 17.6.5.

Comment: Liyun Zhang - MSFT, I don't know but .net Maui sometimes acts strange for example I get that error too if I try to make another page as the mainpage e.g Application.Current.MainPage = some page.

Comment: I never met the problem you mentioned. The `Application.Current.MainPage = some page` always worked well in my project.